# Changing Grid view Details

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a table with role id and user id and gridview with Role ID and User ID, rather than showing the ID'S I would like it to display the user name and roles. How can I change this please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ID's are Foreign keys to other tables that have the name and role. In your SQL, you would need to join those tables to the table that you are displaying in the grid. I use LEFT OUTER JOINS.

thus (generically) you will have something like:

```
SELECT
 t.*
,u.UserName
,r.RoleName
FROM MyTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN myRoleMasterTable r on r.Id = t.RoleId
LEFT OUTER JOIN myUserMasterTable u on u.Id = t.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, you can create a partial class for your entity that display your username and Role.

```
public partial class EntityUserRole
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return User!= null ? User.Name: ""; }
    }
    public string RoleName
    {
        get { return Role!= null ? Role.Name: ""; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table must be something like this..

**tbl_user:**

### userid  | username  | xyz

```
   100   | Jack        | blah
   101   | Matt        | blahh
```

**tbl_role**

### fk_userid  | roleid  | role

```
 101       |  1      | doctor    
 102       |  2      | nurse
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT tbl_user.name, tbl_role.role FROM tbl_user.userid inner join tbl_role 
ON tbl_user.userid = tbl_role.fk_userid
```

Get this in your DataTable or DataSet whatever you are using and then bind your GridView with it like this...

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt ;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Don't hesitate to ask anything which you don't understand.

Comment: actually I have three tables

Comment: tbl user , tbl role and tblUserInRole. TblUserInRole has the two foreign keys. The database is in Access aswell. I am creating the grid view in asp.net how do i go about it please thanks

Comment: You do not know how to show display it in the GridView? Or do you not know the query which you need to get the desired result?